# could not find `__client_accounts_contributor` in the crate root and cannot find type `Withdraw`

Tags: anchor

My code

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_lang::solana_program::pubkey;

declare_id!("8SQ7LtBoufLSXWbcHf7bXuEzFWksbLjE8T7jUi3Yxz1");

#[program]
pub mod cnft {

    use super::*;

    pub fn withdraw_cnft(ctx: Context<Withdraw>) -> Result<()> {

        let merkle_tree = pubkey!("EwxweDQtWzitdmJabX9irUXHbfjTBKujqWVaFtFGr3Gt");
        let lead_index : u32 = 1u32;

        msg!("Transfering CNFT {} from tree {}" , lead_index, merkle_tree);

        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize {}
```

error

```
 error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate`
 --> programs/cnft/src/lib.rs:6:1
  |
6 | #[program]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `__client_accounts_withdraw` in the crate root
  |
  = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

and

```
error[E0412]: cannot find type `Withdraw` in this scope
  --> programs/cnft/src/lib.rs:11:39
   |
11 |     pub fn withdraw_cnft(ctx: Context<Withdraw>) -> Result<()> {
   |                                       ^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need some the `Withdraw` type defined to be used as `Context<Withdraw>`, ie you can just add:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Withdraw {}
```